# Javascript string comparison fails on page load

Tags: javascript, string, match, onload

I have a forum site installed where I added a auto-resize mod which resizes all the images when the page is loaded

```
<script>

    window.onload = resizeimg;

    function resizeimg()
    {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName)
        {
            for (i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName('img').length; i++)
            {
                var check = 0;
                var str = 'http://sariylakirmizi.net/forum/styles/milky_way_red/imageset/sitelogo_small.png';

                im = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i];
                var n =str.match(/sitelogo/gi);
                if(n == null)
                    check = 1;

                if (im.width > 600 &&  im.src !=str )
                {
                    im.style.width = '600px';

                    eval("pop" + String(i) + " = new Function(\"pop = window.open('" + im.src + "','phpbbegypt','fullscale','width=400,height=400,scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); pop.focus();\")");

                    eval("im.onclick = pop" + String(i) + ";");

                    if (document.all) im.style.cursor = 'hand';

                    if (!document.all) im.style.cursor = 'pointer';

                    im.title=im.src;
                    im.alt=check;
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Now what I am trying to is exclude my header logo, so that it would not be resized for that I introduced the string comparison and hardcoded my logo URL, I do not  understand why that check fails and my logo still got resized; I also tried several other things like introducing a check variable whether the match function is working but obviously it does noet work, could you please help me with that?

Comment: Can you paste the HTML snippet of your logo image?

Comment: Where did you get that horrible code? It must be like a decade old and even then it was probably horrible with that `eval` abuse. Please throw it away.

Comment: `<img src="./styles/milky_way_red/imageset/sitelogo_small.png" width="1026" height="90" alt="" title="">`

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yeah it is an old one, but I need to install something to resize the images otherwise my page gets wider where I use a fixed width

Comment: Why not simply use the CSS `max-width` property? Anyway, trust me, you **do not want to use this code**.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I doubt that will solve the issue, the users are simply linking the images in the forum where the images are wider than the forum width.

Comment: It will apply anyway. Try e.g. `img { max-width: 600px; }` in your CSS.

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks, If users will not be happy with this solution I'll stick to that, is there any problem regarding security with this code?

Comment: From a quick look users *might* be able to inject JavaScript code through the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = resizeimg;

function resizeimg() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName) {
        var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
           var im = imgs[i];
           if (im.width > 600 && !im.src.match(/sitelogo/)) {
               im.style.width = '600px';
               eval("pop" + String(i) + " = new Function(\"pop = window.open('" + im.src + "','phpbbegypt','fullscale','width=400,height=400,scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); pop.focus();\")");
               eval("im.onclick = pop" + String(i) + ";");
               im.style.cursor = (document.all) ? 'hand' : 'pointer';
               im.title = im.src;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite a bit, honestly... but the main point of failure is that you didn't have any actual comparison between the img src and your sitelogo.

Comment: but in the test I have the following check : `im.src !=str`

Comment: There are some possibilities... one of which is that the source code may be using a relative path to the logo, (eg, `src="/forum/styles/milky_way_red/imageset/sitelogo_small.png"`, in which case your `str` variable may be too specific.